# Does template match look through all elements in XSLT?

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

If I have XSL such as the following:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p> <xsl:value-of select="artist"/> </p>
  <p> <xsl:value-of select="title"/> </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Will XSLT go through the entire source XML, looking for all elements named `cd`, regardless of their depth?

Comment: The standard processing in XSLT (1 and 2, at least) is parsing the complete XML input document into a tree model which is the processed as the input data structure by the XSLT stylesheet code. Whether your template matching `cd` elements (any, the way you have written it) is actually used at all, depends on the other templates you might have, if for elements or nodes higher up in the tree they stop (recursive) processing of e.g. children or descendants then no `cd` elements might be processed at all.

Comment: @Martin In what order does it traverse the tree? Breadth first or depth first?

Comment: @CJ7 That's implementation dependent and should be irrelevant. What you're missing with the XSLT snippet you show are the default templates that govern the traversal of the input tree when you did not provide any templates of your own: `<xsl:template match="*|/"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` (*"for every element your see, process its children"*) and `<xsl:template match="text()|@*"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>` ("for every text node you see, output its value."*). The first rule is what makes the XSLT processor arrive at your `<xsl:template match="cd">` eventually.

Comment: There is no pre-defined processing order, if I use e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::article-list[2]/preceding::cd"/></xsl:template>` then the navigation selects the second `article-list` descendant element of the document node to process the preceding `cd` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a template rule doesn't do anything of its own accord; it only does anything in response to an `xsl:apply-templates` instruction (explicit or implicit). So the real question is, what does `xsl:apply-templates` do?

The `xsl:apply-templates` instruction has a `select` instruction which selects the nodes to be processed, defaulting to the children of the current node. For each of these, it chooses the best-fit template rule that matches the nodes.

So there's never a search of the entire source XML, rather there is a search of the stylesheet for the rules that best match each node selected for processing.

The most common design pattern is for each template rule to process the children of the current node, in which case the stylesheet as a whole does a recursive tree walk of the entire source document, visiting each node once. But that's just a design pattern, it's not how every stylesheet has to work.

The search of the stylesheet can of course be optimised by the XSLT processor so it doesn't have to match every template rule against every selected node. Every XSLT processor will have its own ways of doing that.

Comment: So is there an implicit `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" />` run by default for every XSL file?

Comment: The initial stylesheet invocation generally does an implicit `<apply-templates select="/"/>`, that is, it finds the template rule that best matches the root (document) node of the source document.